# Exporting Excel to Dataset ( ERROR - TOO MANY FIELDS DEFINED )

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I am exporting a Excel (.xls) sheet to dataset. In that excel i am having 16 columns. While exporting i am getting the error " TOO MANY FIELDS DEFINED "..

Here is my code part..

```
{
            string strFilePathOnServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RevenueDumpFileLocation"];
            String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(strFilePathOnServer) + RevenueDumpFileUpload.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";

            string strPostedFileName = RevenueDumpFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
            if (strPostedFileName != string.Empty && RevenueDumpFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0)
            {

                RevenueDumpFileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFilePathOnServer) + RevenueDumpFileUpload.FileName);
                RevenueDumpFileUpload.FileContent.Dispose();
            }

            OleDbConnection Exlcon = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
            try
            {
                //Exlcon.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Owner$]", Exlcon);
            OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
            objDataset1.Clear();
            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "XLData");
```

When crossing the Fill method, i am getting the error...

How to sort out this...

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1641350.aspx/1?Importing+Excel+data+Too+many+fields+

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938569/oledb-exception-too-many-fields-defined-while-uplaoding-excel-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the column to only 250

```
string sql = "select * from [A1:IU]";
```

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that the limit is 250 columns?  I ran into the same problem with an Excel sheet that had a bunch of extra empty but initialized columns, and just deleting those extra empty columns fixes it.  I can't rely on user intervention though, and would like to know that 250 is the definitive max number of columns you can have if you're going to fill a dataset from an excel sheet.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I was on vacations. Appears to be Jet limitation (check connection string).